# save substring from a string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, stringwithformat

i am having a string like: `funcname("data")`,comes from upstairs.now i want to save the funcname, data in two NSString variables i.e i need to find the string present in between `""` and the string before`'('`.

Comment: "save" has many different meanings.  Save like to the disk; or save like retain?

Comment: its not save...,store the values for further use in the function.

Comment: So just keep a reference to it then.

Comment: nic...but i am unable to differentiate both the data& func name....

Comment: xcode is an ide — it does not run your program, it is not the framework u use to create your program. it is just an editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very useful class NSScanner that will help you to parse different tokens easily.